# What is the meaning of put us on deals?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Early on in my career as an investment banker, I asked to work with the biggest, baddest, scariest VP that ever walked the halls of Goldman Sachs. And my staffer who **put us on deals**, looked at me like I was crazy. No one in the history of time had ever asked to work with Will.

According to Cambridge dictionary, "put someone on something" means to order that someone start taking a particular medicine or eating or avoiding certain foods:
Ex.
Doctors put her on antibiotics after discovering an infection.

But I don't think this definition from Cambridge is applicable to the statement above.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the staffer allocated work on deals (whatever that work consisted of, I've never worked for Goldman Sachs) to the junior members of the workforce.

The same turn of phrase is used for being allocated to any task in any environment. For instance a team of garment workers might be 'put on the new season's blouses' meaning that they would be making those blouses until they were 'taken off' them. Similarly a second line call centre worker might be 'put on complaints', a police officer might be 'put on traffic duty' or a water company employee might be 'put on sewer blockages'.

Sometimes someone who is sick or has been injured while doing the job can be 'put on light duties' when they return to work meaning that they aren't expected to lift anything or put themselves at risk.

Answer (score 1):

The “on” in the Cambridge dictionary’s example: “Doctors put her **on** antibiotics”, i.e. *"to put someone on something" means to order that someone start”* is the same “on” as in *“And my staffer who put us **on** deals,”*. It means to start someone doing something, or to allocate something (an object or a task) to someone.

Comment: My Lancashire wife says that something eaten between meals to stave off hunger pangs, will 'put me on'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's much more widely used than just Lancashire. It's familiar to me from most northern English dialects and my mother, who was from Herefordshire originally, used to use it regularly.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - perhaps it is something from the West - I've lived mostly in the East and the "opposite" is used: "start you off".